# PHP Post-Content Length Exceeds Limit

Tags: php, file-upload

My image uploader has an error message set to display when images that are uploaded are greater than a certain size. However, if I upload something that is REALLY big, the error message gets bypassed and the user is stuck seeing the POST Content-Length exceeded error message that I don't want them to see. Can someone please help me figure out why image files that are too large don't get the error message displayed?

Here is the verify function that gets called when a photo is uploaded:

```
//------------------------------
private function _verify($fn) {
//------------------------------
    global $_WEBCONFIG;

    $isValid = TRUE;
    $userID = isset($_POST["hidId"]) ? (int)$_POST["hidId"] : 0;
    $this->record2->p_id = $this->proId;

    $fieldName  = "txtName";
    $fieldValue = SanitizeData($_POST[$fieldName]);
    if (!$fieldValue || strlen($fieldValue = trim($fieldValue)) == 0) {
        $this->record2->i_name = '';
    } else {
        $this->record2->i_name = $fieldValue;
    }

    $fieldName  = "fleImage";
    if (isset($_FILES[$fieldName]) && strlen($_FILES[$fieldName]['name']) > 0) {
        $fieldValue = $_FILES[$fieldName]['name'];
        $file_ext   = strtolower(GetExtName($fieldValue));
        $arExts     = explode(",", VALID_IMGS);

        if (!in_array($file_ext, $arExts)) {
            $this->errors[] = "Invalid Image Format. (Allowed image types: " . VALID_IMGS . ")";
            $isValid = FALSE;
        } else {
            $size = getimagesize($_FILES[$fieldName]['tmp_name']);
             if ($size[0] < $_WEBCONFIG['THUMB_WIDTH'] || $size[1] < $_WEBCONFIG['THUMB_HEIGHT']) {
                $this->errors[] = "Invalid Image Size. (Image Dimensions: " . $_WEBCONFIG['IMAGE_WIDTH'] . " x " . $_WEBCONFIG['IMAGE_HEIGHT'] . " or larger)";
                $isValid = FALSE;
             }

             $imageSize = filesize($_FILES[$fieldName]['tmp_name']);
             if ($imageSize > 16777216){
                $this->errors[] = "Invalid File Size. File size must be smaller than 128 MB.";
                $isValid = FALSE;
             }

        }
    } else if ($fn == 0) {
        $this->errors[] = "Please upload an Image (Image Dimensions: " . $_WEBCONFIG['IMAGE_WIDTH'] . " x " . $_WEBCONFIG['IMAGE_HEIGHT'] . " or larger.)";
        $isValid = FALSE;
    }

    $fieldName  = "txtOrder";
    $fieldValue = SanitizeData($_POST[$fieldName]);
    if (strlen($fieldValue = trim($fieldValue)) == 0) {
        $this->record2->i_sort_id = 99999;
    } else {
        $this->record2->i_sort_id = $fieldValue;
    }

    return $isValid;
}//end function
```

The image size I am uploading that bypasses the error message is 37.4 MB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that error is most probably sent by the server. the server will have settings in the php.ini which could be configured. eg

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 20M
```

the php.ini file is usually stored in /etc/php.ini or /etc/php.d/cgi/php.ini or /usr/local/etc/php.ini but most web hosts provide an option to edit this file within the control panel

Comment: IT won't increase the file size, which is why I need to know how to display an error or get around this within the php file. I tried adding `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');` and the same for `post_max_size` to the top of the update-images.php page, but I still can't catch it.

Comment: you could maybe configure it through .htaccess by adding this to it: `php_value memory_limit 36M`, `php_value post_max_size 36M`, `php_value upload_max_filesize 32M` or try adding multiple ini_set like: `ini_set('meemory_limit', '96M');`, `ini_set('post_max_size', '64M');`, `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '64M');`

Comment: I don't have access to the htaccess, but I added the rest of those ini_set like you suggested and I just can't get past it. I was just going to add text to the upload page that links customers to an image compressor site, but every online image compressor errors out on the image I try to upload too. It's just too dang big!

Comment: Since adding code to the php file didn't work, I begged and pleaded with IT to increase the size on the server, so we are all good now! Thanks for your help!